# Render Open Streetmap map as bitmap of known scale

Tags: android, openstreetmap

How would I use OpenStreetMap on Android to generate a map as a bitmap whose center point corresponds to a specific location (like (25.60156, -80.41306)), each pixel of which represents an area that's approximately 100 meters from north to south, and approximately 70-100 meters from east to west?

For the purposes of this example, assume that I want the map to include high-level details like country/state outlines, county outlines, and major roads. I don't want to litter the map with things like city names, minor roads, transit lines, bodies of water, etc.

I've seen hundreds of examples that show how to embed an OSM map into an Android app AS a map app, but there seems to be surprisingly little information about using OSM as a library to generate maps as bitmaps for use by something ELSE (like a 8192 x 4096 bitmap suitable for use as an OpenGL ES 2.0 texture).

I'm open to using Google Maps, of course... but as far as I can tell, Google Maps doesn't just lack an API to do this, it's explicitly forbidden by its TOS to do anything with their map data besides embed it verbatim AS a Google MapView.

I'm also open to other ideas, like using free public GIS data... but I've gotten the impression that even most "free" GIS data is somehow encumbered by ESRI and restricted for commercial use (possibly via patents, or maybe by claiming ownership of data files generated by their software).

Note: I'd prefer to fetch map data from some public server and do all the map-generation locally under Android, but if that's a completely hopeless task, an alternative might be to generate the map bitmaps on my web server and serve them as needed to my app's users.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is roughly the idea of a "Static Map" - a web service that creates bitmaps for specific geographic areas and returns it as an image. Many companies provide this as a service, and tend to have terms that permit you to use those images as images in HTML or textures on mobile devices.

Here's the [Google Maps Static implementation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro) and [Mapbox Static Maps API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#static). Both support custom styling that lets you remove unnecessary visual features; it's the focus of Mapbox as part of [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/) but is also [Google Maps supports styled maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling).

*Full disclosure: I work for Mapbox*.

In terms of requesting images at a specific scale measured in meters, this [table of resolution and scale](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Resolution_and_Scale) should get you going.